# Repeat execution of java method using values in spark dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, methods

I have a method that contains if else statements to run code based on a string value that is passed to a method.

```
private Dataset<Row> getData(Dataset<Row> config, String controlValue) {

if (controlValue.equals(text1) {

Do this... 

} else if (controlValue.equals(text2) {

Do this... 

}
```

Is there a way to loop through rows of a dataset and call getData() method based on a values from a specific column.

Comment: it depends on (Do this)... please specify the detail code  of getData

Comment: @kavetiraviteja for text1 I'm connecting to one Oracle Database with a select * from table where filter = 'text1'

Comment: then you can do it .. but you need broadcast text1 values to executors if you are using it in filter transformation.